# Using parent ADFS application to authenticate multiple applications

Tags: .net, iis, single-sign-on, adfs

I'm in the beginning stages of researching the use of ADFS for an application as a resource partner (our client is requesting access to our site).

My initial thought is to develop 1 web application that will handle all ADFS requests/authentications which then redirects to one of our many web-based applications, which are on different servers/app pools etc. The idea is that only the one application needs to be programmed to handle ADFS, the others can be unaware of ADFS and just handle generic authentication through the querystring. Does what I'm trying to accomplish make sense? We are trying to implement ADFS because it's what our client wants to use to access our site(s).

Answer (score 0):

When you configure your first application (RP1) as Relying Party (RP) in ADFS, After authentication ADFS sends access token specific to your application (RP1) based on the configured parameters for RP1(Token identifier, Claims (sometimes encrypted), signing certs,etc..).
You cannot share this token with the other application (e.g. Application 2).

If your intention is to pass the authentication from RP1 - > App2 , is both your web apps linked? 
In that case, you can extract the claims from ADFS token (in RP1) and pass it to the other app (App 2).

Will a user ever access the App2 link directly ?
If a user directly hits the App2 URL, user won't be redirected to ADFS since ADFS is not aware of APP 2.

So you are basically designing a solution where  a  user will always access App2 via RP1 (after ADFS authentication).

The recommended approach will be adding APP 2 as a relying party to ADFS and configure App2 to process ADFS tokens (SAML / WS-FED). 
It provides more security and flexibility (you don't need to change RP1 to make changes to App2) .